# Pandas: df.query() method returns 0 results

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe and using:

`filtered = dataframe[dataframe["x"] == "y"]` returns results.

However, this does not:

`filtered = dataframe.query('x == "y"', inplace=True)` does not.

Comment: Inplace=True does it inplace. It doesn't return anything because it is done in... place. Remove your `inplace=True` argument.

Comment: remove the `inplace=True`

Comment: Thanks! That corrected it

Answer (score 0):

As ifly6 and Yuca pointed out, removing inplace=True resolved this.